# how would I get rid off error 'Manager' object has no attribute 'active'

Tags: django, python-3.x

My search field is not working, I get the error which says "'Manager' object has no attribute 'active'"

I have tried to google and solve it but still I can't remove the error

views.py

```
def IndexView(request):
    query_list = Documents.objects.active()
    if request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser:
        query_list = Documents.objects.all()
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    if query:
        query_list = query_list.filter(Q(docs_name__icontains=query) |
                                   Q(item_type__icontains=query) |

Q(Description__icontains=query)).distinct()


paginator = Paginator(query_list, 5)
page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    qs = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    qs = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    qs = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
title = "Home-Back My Item"



return render(request, "loststuffapp/home.html", context={"documents":Documents.objects.all})
```

model.py

```
class Documents(models.Model):
    docs_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name="Jina la Nyaraka")
    item_type = models.CharField(default="", max_length=100,verbose_name="Aina ya nyaraka" )
    police_station = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Kituo cha polisi")
    phone_no = models.CharField(verbose_name="Namba yako ya simu", max_length=10, blank=False, 
validators=[int_list_validator(sep=''),MinLengthValidator(10),])
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,verbose_name="Date")
    Description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True,verbose_name="Maelezo zaidi")
    pay_no = models.IntegerField(default=0,verbose_name="Namba ya malipo")
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="Documents",blank=False, verbose_name="Picha ya nyaraka")

"""docstring for Documents"""
def __str__(self):
    return self.docs_name
```

home.html

```
    <li>
        <form action="{% url 'loststuffapp:IndexView' %}" method="get">
          <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search..." value=" 
           {{request.GET.q}}">
        </form>
     </li>
```

Comment: How does your `Documents` model look?

Comment: Why do you think `Document.objects.active()` would work? Where did you define  the `active()` method? Apparently not on `objects` since python cannot find it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
query_list = Documents.objects.active()  <---
```

To resolve this, you need to use a default manager methods like `filter`:

```
query_list = Documents.objects.filter(publish=True)
```

Or you can write a [custom manager method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/#creating-a-manager-with-queryset-methods).

Comment: I have made changes but I get another error written as Cannot resolve keyword 'active' into field.

Comment: now, the question is what did you mean by `objects.active()`, does it mean only the published articles?

Comment: am still learning, just copied from some where but the aim is to display the searched input

Comment: don't copy code without understanding what it does. Either follow a tutorial step by step (but then apparently you missed a step since you didn't define `.active()`) or write your own. The code above is making a difference between staff users and non-staff users, so that staff users can also view 'non active' documents (whatever that means). Remove that part of the code and just do: `Document.objects.all()` if you don't need that functionality.